# Creating new form in moodle

Tags: moodle

I have created a new module in `moodle` from the link [New Module](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/NEWMODULE_Documentation). I have installed that as well and it is showing up in the Administration ->Activities.

How to add a new form against that module to get the user inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the mod_form.php in the documentation. This is used to add an instance of the new activity. Please check the existing modules also.